# read serial numbers with regex and place them as individual elements of a List<string>

Tags: c#, regex

I am parsing an excel document and one column includes n number of serial numbers for each row, separated by a white space.

sample serials: 1108656 1108657 1108658 1108659 1108660 1108661 1108662 1108663 1108664 1108665 1108666

how could I use regex to analyze that string and return a List or IEnumerable where each serial number in the sample is an individual element?

serials are between 5 and 8 numbers long.

I am using C# and the .Net Regex.

Comment: You could just use `Split(' ')` or [Regex.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.split.aspx)

Comment: Not sure I understand the question.  It seems you can simply use cell_content.Split(' ') to get an IEnumerable (or Array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the string is simply numbers separated by spaces I'd suggest going with `String.Split` method like this :

```
string[] mySerialNumbers = searchString.Split(new char[]{' '});
```

See the documentation of [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx).

To have the result as an `IEnumerable` you can simply create a `List<string>` with the result of `String.Split` like this :

```
List<string> mySerialNumbers = new List<string>(searchString.Split(new char[]{' '});
```

Edit:

After reading the comment, the Regex way would indeed kind of validate the input to make sure no other characters are there, which is a good thing. The regex for this would be as simple as this :

```
foreach(Match match in Regex.Matches("1108656 1108657 1108658 1108659", "[0-9]{5,8}"))
{
    // Do something with match.Value here like : int.Parse(match.Value)
}
```

The regex expression [0-9]{5,8} means any digit repeated between 5 and 8 times. Of course this Regex is really simple and will simply capture the good things. For example as tring with 1234567 abcd 7654321 will not give any error, it will simply capture the 2 numbers and silently ignore the letters. You could make a much more complex regex to validate even better. This could be a solid starting reference for regex : http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet

Comment: it was what I originally wanted to do, but with regex I could check the data to make sure that there were no letters or symbols. this could be done with split and come foreachs, but learning to do it in regex would probably be a better option in the long run.

Comment: @user1134704: It would probably be a good idea to make it clear what you're trying to do in your question. You've gotten 4 answers and 2 comments which basically boil down to "You just need to do a 'Split' to do what you're asking."

Comment: @user1134704 So what do you want to do if there is an entry with letters in it?  Throw out that entry?  Throw out the line?

Comment: @Servy in that case I have to ignore that serial and add the error to a log.

Comment: @ThatChuckGuy thanks, that is some solid advice, I am just starting out here and your tips are welcome.

Answer (score -1):

Regex.Spilt method can be used here

```
string[] SerialNum = Regex.Split("yourStringVar", " ")
```